# Is ActiveRecord::Base.logger different then rails logger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

if I set ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level what its effect on config.log_level (Rails 5)?

I could not find documentation on ActiveRecord log levels - are all sql queries output to the same level? what is it?

Can I stop SQL queries log only from config.log_level?

Thanks a log ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default ActiveRecord uses the same instance of logger as Rails (`ActiveRecord::Base.logger.object_id == Rails.logger.object_id # => true`). This means that changing log level on AR is going to change `config.log_level`.
What you can do is you can set another logger instance for AR like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = :warn
```

(place it into e.g. `config/application.rb`)
This way it won't affect `config.log_level`

Comment: thanks! can you tell what is the maximal level to put on activerecord to not see sql queries? couldn't find what activerecords prints to what level

Comment: @dowi SQL queries are printed on lowest level which is debug. Just set it to `:info`.